# Netgear wnr2000v3 - no Internet connection

Tags: networking, router, internet, modem

I bought a Netgear wnr2000v3 about a year ago and everything was running fine for months. There are 8 devices connected to the router, 3 directly connected, 2 over WiFi and 3 passing a switch.

Now, since approx. a month, it happens like once a week that the connection to the modem crashes and I'm unable to access the Internet for about 3-4 hours anymore. I'm still able to connect to the router, where it is stated that there's no Internet connection. When I connect a PC directly to the modem, everything is fine, so there doesn't seem to be any problems with my ISP.

Is this problem well-known? What can I do about it?

I updated to the last firmware, tried it out with only 1 device connected to the router, reset factory defaults, rebuilt the physical setup. Is there a way to gain access to internal log files?

Answer (score -1):

If you have downloaded netgear genie on your computer go into your control panel and uninstall it. Just use routerlogin.net to do any router controls that you need (login:admin password:password). The genie can act like a virus on your Internet connection and ISP connection constantly dropping signal from it. I was having the same problem while streaming Netflix from any device and as soon as I did this it stopped all the disconnects. Hope this helps

Comment: Or you could also try downgrading your firmware.